# Use SynchronizationContext only on Task RanToCompletion

Tags: c#, async-await, task, synchronizationcontext

The code below explains the idea

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result;
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(3000).Token;

        try
        {
            result = await GetDataAsync(cancellationToken)
                .ContextIfSuccess();    // Should use SynchronizationContext only if Task status is RanToCompletion
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {
            /* Context is not required */
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /* Context is not required otherwise it can slow down UI Thread a little bit */
            Log(ex.ToString());
            return;
        }

        /* UI Thread only */
        button1.Text = result;
    }
```

The question is "Is it possible to make the method like ContextIfSuccess() ?"

Comment: Why does an implementation detail such as `SynchronizationContext` matters to you?

Comment: Because I don't want to interrupt UI Thread for no reason especially on mobile devices

Comment: Then use an async buffer for logging? log4j provides that out of the box. Also, is this really a noticeable performance hit?

Comment: Log() is just an example of the work what better should not bother the UI Thread

Comment: Note that your method because *much* cleaner when you change the `try` to just `button1.Text = await ...`.  There's then no reason for the `result` variable or the `return` calls; it just needlessly complicates the code.

Comment: @Servy I write it that way only just because I was think it would be easy to understand the idea and there we have place to put the important comment /* UI Thread only */ :-)

Comment: @Miles It would go *inside* the `try`, after the await.  That's where you *actually* need to use the UI thread, and that comes out just fine in the code.  If you want to store the data in a variable *local to the `try`* then it wouldn't be a problem.  But anyway, as long as you know not to write code like this for real that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the method that you want you'll need to create a custom awaiter.  It's mostly boilerplate, the key is simply that, when asked to add a continuation, you add one using the current sync context to run on successful completion, and one using the default scheduler when it doesn't run to completion.

```
public struct CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    private Task task;

    public CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter(Task task)
    {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter GetAwaiter() { return this; }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
        {
            task.ContinueWith(t => continuation(),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            task.ContinueWith(t => continuation(),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
        else
        {
            task.ContinueWith(t => continuation(),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
    }

    public void GetResult() { task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }
    public bool IsCompleted { get { return task.GetAwaiter().IsCompleted; } }
}

public struct CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter<T> : INotifyCompletion
{
    private Task<T> task;

    public CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter(Task<T> task)
    {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() { return this; }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
        {
            task.ContinueWith(t => continuation(),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            task.ContinueWith(t => continuation(),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
        else
        {
            task.ContinueWith(t => continuation(),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
    }

    public T GetResult() { return task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }
    public bool IsCompleted { get { return task.GetAwaiter().IsCompleted; } }
}
```

```
public static CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter ContextIfSuccess(this Task task)
{
    return new CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter(task);
}

public static CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter<T> ContextIfSuccess<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    return new CaptureContextOnSuccessAwaiter<T>(task);
}
```

Comment: But does task.ContinueWith without 'await' would Disposed by GC in anytime?

Comment: @Miles The `ContinueWith` is going to be called *when the object is awaited*.  This is a custom awaiter, so the compiler will generate a call to `OnCompleted` whenever the object is awaited.  As for the GC disposing of it, no, there will be a reference to the continuation by the running task, which will have references to it from the scheduler, which will be rooted.  You basically never need to worry about a continuation that could theoretically ever be called in the future ever being collected; any task that could ever fire its continuations would need to be alive.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I have one more question. Would it be better to do it in that way? ![Valid XHTML](http://joxi.ru/5mdEazUkkDQV21.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

`await` without context (`ConfigureAwait(false)`). Then, if the desired condition is true you switch into the context.

So you will need to capture `SynchronizationContext.Current` and `Post` to that.

This is very similar to what `TaskAwaiter` does anyway. It resumed without context, then switched back into the context if the caller desires so.

You should be able to make this into a `ContextIfSuccess` method. Basically, clone the `TaskAwaiter` source code and decide whether to `Post` or not in the completion notification. This feature is already there I assume. The code must look at the `ConfigureAwait(...)` value and conditionally apply the context or not.

Comment: I understand you point but the idea was make it simple as single method "ContextIfSuccess()"

Comment: Why not `button1.Invoke` instead?

Comment: I prefer button1.Text = await GetDataAsync(); rather than Invoke UI Thread manually

Comment: @Miles I missed that. Added. Why are you doing this? Perf optimization?

Comment: @usr Exactly! For the mobile systems

Comment: Makes sense I guess. You could pass in a `Func<Task, bool>` to make the method reusable. You can then pass an arbitrary predicate.

Comment: Didn't catch that. However I already tried make the custom ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T> with no luck;

Comment: Well, then you probably should detail why it did not work... ; I was thinking of something like `ContextIf(task => task.IsSuccess)`. You could even inspect the task result there.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That's winforms specific.  The code wouldn't work if you moved it to a WPF app, an ASP application, a mobile app (which happens to be the case here), etc.  By using `SynchronizationContext` you not only handle *all* of these, but you handle custom sync context that any of your code, or library code, may use, as well as pretty much any future products MS may come out with that would have anything resembling a UI context.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov MSDN says the UI Thread is the one thread what definitely has SynchronizationContext, in my case is what I need

Comment: @Servy Sure, this doesn't handle all super duper MS technologies, but how maintainable is this really? How many people really understand the semantics oh a synchronization context? And who said at all that it needs to be so generic? Micro optimizing a synchronization context switch is something that would usually be neglectable in measurements, and if OP, for some reason, has time consuming operations in a `catch` clause, he should think about what he's doing.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  You think using an operation specific to a particular technology is *more* maintainable than a simple operation that will work for *any* technology?  How does that work?  If you don't know what a synchronization context is, you shouldn't be writing asynchronous code like this.  It's a very simple concept, and you should at least know what it is, what it's role is.  As for whether or not it makes sense to be mindful of what continuations do and don't use it, that depends a lot on the program.  Library code, for example, absolutely does need to be mindful of this.

Comment: @Servy *You think using an operation specific to a particular technology is more maintainable than a simple operation that will work for any technology?* Most of the times, yes. The more you abstract away with implicit operations, the less likely a group of developers are likely to comprehend everything. *If you don't know what a synchronization context is, you shouldn't be writing asynchronous code like this* What is *like this*? I love how you always have tons of hidden assumptions in your comments, yet you state them like they're the absolute truth.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov By "like this" I'm referring to code using `await` and the TPL, as it's very much based on using synchronization contexts.  You shouldn't be using those operations if you don't at least know what a synchronization context is.  Why would you bother learning some very narrow, technology specific way of performing an operation, that's similar but subtly different in each technology, when you could just use a very simple and straightforward object that will work in any technology and performs the operation very simply and just as effectively.

Comment: @Servy Why? Because people can. For the same reason why not all developers have 152k point on StackOverflow. High level programming languages provide enough abstraction exactly so developers don't focus on the how, but on the what. I find it hard to understand your naiveness, especially as someone who's been around here long enough. Bringing in a general, high level abstraction can also make it easy for people to abuse.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, people can use the less maintainable solution that is no simpler, and is much more fragile, require more maintenance over time.  That doesn't make it more maintainable.  I have no objection to the idea of abstracting away the mechanism; that's why I'm suggesting using an abstraction that avoids the mechanism, rather than always including a technology specific mechanism and changing it over time.  Yes, tools can be used improperly; all tools can be.  That doesn't make this an improper use of a sync context.